# Loop through PHP and target with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, loops

I have this function for tooltips:

```
//Tooltips
(function($) {
    $.fn.tooltips = function(html) {
        var $tooltip,
            $html;
        return this.each(function(data, html) {
            $html = $(html).attr("data-tooltip", data);
            var $tooltip = $('<div class="tooltip" data-tooltip="' + data + '">' + $html.attr('title') + '</div>').appendTo(".tip");
            $html.removeAttr("title").hover(function() {
                $html = $(this);
                $tooltip = $('div[data-tooltip=' + $html.data('tooltip') + ']');
                $tooltip.addClass("active");
            }, function() {
                $html = $(this);
                $tooltip = $('div[data-tooltip=' + $html.data('tooltip') + ']');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $tooltip.removeClass("active");
                }, 100);
            });
        });
    }
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
    $("a.tip[title]").tooltips();
});
```

And I have a PHP loop with this:

```
echo '<span class="author-meta"><a class="author tip" id="'. $username .'" href="#" title="[Removed]">'. $username .'</a></span><br>';
```

Currently when you hover over one name, all the title tags appear on all the names. **Is there an easy method to have it so if you hover over one name - Only that name has the hover event?**

The code is from a free tutorial website that I can't seem to find anymore but I don't remember this particular issue being mentioned in the comment section so I'm at a loss!

Comment: I found similar code on: http://css-tricks.com/bubble-point-tooltips-with-css3-jquery/

Comment: That's the one! No help though :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake in your code is in:

```
.appendTo(".tip")
```

That is appending the tooltip to all the elements with class="tip". You should only append to the current element. The code in line 8 should be:

```
var $tooltip = $('<div class="tooltip" data-tooltip="' + data + '">' + $html.attr('title') + '</div>').appendTo(this);
```

Comment: Aha! So simple! Thank you!